# Writing a deposit method in C++, Having trouble

Tags: c++, xcode, methods

I'm writing a method that accepts the value of amount to be deposited, as a parameter. If the amount is greater than bal (balance) the account will be updated with the new amount. Otherwise it returns the old bal and exits. Here is my code:

```
double withdraw(double amount)
{
    if((bal-amount)<0)
    {
        throw new Exception
        ("There were insufficient funds");
        else
            bal=bal-amount;
        return bal;

    }
}
```

I'm having errors with the Exception and the else statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have placed the `{ }` in the wrong place.

```
double withdraw(double amount)
{
    if((bal-amount)<0)
    {
        throw new Exception("There were insufficient funds");
    }
    else
    {
        bal=bal-amount;
    }
    return bal;
}
```

Comment: ahh yeah now i see it. oops.